# Scaling in Mehta's integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, random-matrices

The following expression is known as Mehta's integral and deeply connected to random matrix theory:

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-t_i^2/2}
\prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} |t_i - t_j |^{2 \gamma} dt_1 \cdots dt_n =\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{\Gamma(1+j\gamma)}{\Gamma(1+\gamma)}.$$

An interesting question is what happens if one assumes $\gamma$ to be a function of $n.$
For example by choosing $\gamma=1/n$ one finds that as $n$ tends to infinity, the value of the integral tends to zero whereas for $\gamma=1/n^2$ the value of the integral approaches a positive constant value as $n$ tends to infinity.

These properties one can deduce from the asymptotics of the product of gamma functions. I would like to ask:

It is not too surprising that for some suitable scaling $\gamma=1/n^{\alpha}$ one approaches a constant value, as $\vert t_i-t_j \vert^{1/n} \xrightarrow 1$ for fixed $t_i,t_j$ and

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-t_i^2/2}
dt_1 \cdots dt_n =1.$$

Can one also conclude these two properties from the integral directly without evaluating it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this follows by the [de la Vallée-Poussin necessary and sufficient condition for the uniform integrability](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/2013spring-stat210b/notes/5notes.pdf). Indeed, suppose that 
\begin{equation}
 \gamma n^2\to a
\end{equation}
(as $n\to\infty$) for some real $a\ge0$. 
Your integral is 
$$E\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|X_i-X_j|^{2\gamma},$$
where the $X_i$'s are independent standard normal random variables. 
Introducing $N:=n(n-1)/2$, $X:=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, and $\|X\|:=\sqrt{\sum_1^n X_i^2}$, and then using the arithmetic-geometric-mean inequality, we have 
$$\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|X_i-X_j|^{2\gamma}
\le\Big(\frac1N\,\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}|X_i-X_j|^2\Big)^{N\gamma} \\ 
=O\Big(\frac{\|X\|^2}n\Big)^{N\gamma}=O\Big(1+\frac{\|X\|^2}n\Big)^C
$$
for $C:=a/2+1$ and all large enough $n$.

Note also that $\|X\|^2$ has the gamma distribution with parameters $n/2$ and $2$ and hence $E\|X\|^{2C}=O(n^C)$. So, 
$$E\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|X_i-X_j|^{2\gamma}=O(1)$$
and, similarly, 
$$E\Big[\Big(\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|X_i-X_j|^{2\gamma}\Big)^2\Big]=O(1).$$
Also, obviously, $t^2/t\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$. So, we have the uniform integrability.

So, we only need to establish the convergence of 
\begin{equation*}
 {2\gamma}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\ln|X_i-X_j|=2\gamma NU_n
\end{equation*}
in probability, where 
\begin{equation*}
 U_n:=\frac1N\,\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}h(X_i,X_j) 
\end{equation*}
is a so-called U-statistic with kernel $h(X_i,X_j):=\ln|X_i-X_j|$, and still $N=\binom n2=n(n-1)/2$. It is easy to see (cf. e.g. [page 20](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/2013spring-stat210b/notes/5notes.pdf)) that $Var\,U_n=O(1/n)=o(1)$, whereas 
$$EU_n=m:=E\ln|X_1-X_2|.$$ 
So, $U_n\to m$ in probability, whence 
\begin{equation*}
 2\gamma NU_n\to am
\end{equation*}
in probability and thus, by the uniform integrability,
$$E\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}|X_i-X_j|^{2\gamma}\to e^{am}=\exp\{a\,E\ln|X_1-X_2|\}$$ 
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: interesting, but how did you estimate this product? Also, the dimension of the integral changes, which is perhaps a bit different from the usual DCT.

Comment: @SolidStatePhysicist : I have added the requested details.

Comment: @SolidStatePhysicist : You were right. I had indeed overlooked that the dimension of the integral, $n$, goes to infinity. This is now fixed. Instead of the integration over $\mathbb R^n$, with the variable $n$, we now use the expectation, which is the integration over a fixed background probability space. Instead of dominated convergence, we now use uniform integrability, which complicates the reasoning just a bit.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I think there is an issue with this answer. The OP claims and asking for a proof that this property holds for $\gamma=1/n^2$. In your answer however, you assume that $\gamma=o(1/n^2).$ This seems to be irrelevant for the uniform integrability, although the property is mentioned there, but it is clearly used to show convergence in probability. I'd be curious to hear what you think?

Comment: @XinWang good point, I guess this point would require some clarification. I think I looked through the proof too fast when I read it and was satisfied to see that it was essentially uniform integrab. + convergence in measure

Comment: @IosifPinelis Do you see a way to extend your argument to $\gamma=\mathcal O(1/n^2)$ rather than $o(1/n^2)$?

Comment: @XinWang : I have added the modification you requested.

Comment: @SolidStatePhysicist : I have added the modification you requested.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: I have now combined the cases $\gamma=o(1/n^2)$ and $\gamma\sim a/n^2$ for real $a>0$ into one case: $\gamma n^2\to a\ge0$.